# How might one connect a laptop's aux out to an oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, sound

I am using an online pure tone generator (which generates sinusoidal sound waves) on my laptop to output sound.

The AUX-out jack on laptops outputs sound in analog rather than digital signals. Unless I am mistaken in my thought process, in theory, I should be able to somehow display this signal on an oscilloscope.

The only input the oscilloscope I have has is a CH/BNC input and digging through the lab equipment I have found a device that fits into the CH jack and has two crocodile clips (red/black) coming out of it.

Similarly I have also found another device that connects to the CH/BNC jack with red/black binding posts, shown below.

[image: CH to red/black binding posts]

I have access to a male-to-male aux (3.5mm) cable. Is there anything I can do with this setup to view the audio signal outputting from my laptop on the oscilloscope? Looking around online did not help my particular case. I thought of connecting a microphone to the oscilloscope and placing this mic next to my laptop's speaker, however this is obviously less accurate (variable mic quality, takes in background noise, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Take a scope probe, connect the ground clip to the metal barrel of the 3.5mm aux connector and the probe itself to the tip of the connector. Plug the other end of the male-male aux lead into the aux output. You will now get one channel on the scope, provided you've set it up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not "crocodile clips", they are binding posts.

You could take a 3.5mm cable of any kind (perhaps from a broken headphone), cut off whatever is on the other end and put one wire under each of the binding posts. If your oscilloscope and computer are both grounded to earth you will have to get the wire that's connected to the chassis of the computer on the black binding post.

Pinout is as follows:

[image]

You could also buy a [female 3.5mm socket](http://www.cui.com/product/resource/digikeypdf/sj1-351x_series.pdf) (model 3513) and wire it to the binding posts.

Comment: Indeed the picture shows binding posts, if you'll reread my post I've said that that was another device. My wording wasn't that clear though, my bad. Thanks for this